# C++ and DirectShow

Tags: c++, winapi, com, directshow

I'm just getting started with DirectShow programming, and the 'C' nature of the DirectShow API is making my skin crawl. Endless return codes instead of exceptions, addref/release all over the place, functions taking pointer to pointers...

Are there any 'C++ friendly' wrappers for DirectShow programming that hide all the COM ugliness underneath.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 98% of DirectShow code, you should *never* see a call to AddRef or Release.  Always use [CComPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)<>.  There are a few minor exceptions to this rule.

Also, understanding locking is important, as is CCritSec and CAutoLock; once again, I'd avoid manually locking CCritSec instances because it's a good way to deadlock an application.

Also, this code can be pretty handy:

```
#include <dxerr9.h>

...

HRESULT hr = S_OK;

... something goes wrong ...

CString err(::DXGetErrorString9(hr));
err += ::DXGetErrorDescription9(hr);
```

Lastly, make sure you're using the DShow eventing.  All sorts of useful info comes in over events from a DShow graph, and it's surprising how many applications don't have this implemented (or have it implemented incorrectly).

A while ago, [I wrote this](http://goldfishforthought.blogspot.com/2008/04/n-habits-of-highly-defective-directshow.html), which I've sort of tossed together a few of the pitfalls of working with DShow.  Sadly, I know these pitfalls because I've screwed up in almost all these ways.

Answer (score 3):

[CComPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a pretty handy one,

Beyond that you just have to live with things like the HRESULTS.  I rather prefer them to exceptions ... find them much easier to work with ... each to their own.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth knowing that DirectShow is implemented in `quartz.dll`, and DirectShow Editing Services in `qedit.dll`.

You can use those two with the [Compiler COM Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h31ekh7e%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) from Visual C++ to write DirectShow client applications.

Here is a small play media_file example (compile with cl /D_UNICODE playfile.cpp):

```
#include <iostream> 

#import <quartz.dll> rename_namespace("dshow") 
#import <qedit.dll> rename_namespace("dshow")

// Required for CLSID_FilterGraph
#include <uuids.h> 
#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids.lib")

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[]) 
{  
    using namespace dshow;
    using namespace std;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        wcout << "Usage: play media_file" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    struct ComInitializer
    {
        ComInitializer() 
        { 
            ::CoInitialize(0);
        }

        ~ComInitializer()
        {
            ::CoUninitialize();
        }
    } comInit;

    try 
    { 
        IGraphBuilderPtr graphBuilder; 
        graphBuilder.CreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph); 

        graphBuilder->RenderFile(argv[1], 0);

        IMediaControlPtr mediaControl = graphBuilder;
        mediaControl->Run();

        wcout << "Press Return to stop playback." << endl;
        wcin.get();

        mediaControl->Stop();
    } 
    catch (const _com_error& err)
    {
        wcout << L"Error code: 0x" << hex << err.Error() << endl;
    }
}
```

I've used this method in building a console [DirectShow oggenc](http://cristianadam.blogspot.com/2009/03/directshow-oggenc-v01.html) application.

Comment: Any clue as to why this isn't used in the DirectShow documentation and other online examples? The MSXML documentation has a separate section describing how to make use of these auto-generated smart pointers.

Comment: Probably they don't know about this. Documentation and the book, are very C-style oriented. This style looks more like DirectShow.NET.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't find a wrapper then you can possibly benefit from the coding pattern discussed in my blog entry ["B true, or B thrown! (Using the >> throwing pattern)"](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/07/18/cppx-b-true-or-b-thrown-using-the-throwing-pattern/).

Example from that blog entry (this can easily be adapted for COM, and in fact I first "invented" it for COM usage):

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& stream, wchar_t const s[] )
{
    Size const  nBytes      = wcstombs( 0, s, 0 );
    (nBytes >= 0)
        || throwX( "wcstombs failed to deduce buffer size" );

    Size const              bufSize     = nBytes + 1;
    std::vector< char >     buf( bufSize );

    // The count of bytes written does not include terminating nullbyte.
    wcstombs( &buf[0], s, bufSize )
        >> Accept< IsNonNegative >()
        || throwX( "wcstombs failed to convert string" );

    return (stream << &buf[0]);
}
```

There is some discussion at the blog, evidently everybody has his or her own preference for suitable operators etc., so I'm just throwing in the *general principle* here.

Oh, should add, instead of `AddRef` and `Release` calls, just use some COM smart pointer. There are so many of them around (e.g. in ATL/MFC, and the "intrinsic" one for Visual C++) that it's just pick and choose the one you like. Or create your own e.g. based on `boost::intrusive_ptr`.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Each to their own but I find your construct above completely unfathomable.  It is not even slightly obvious what its doing at a glance and as such, IMO, it is a bad programming construct ...

Comment: @Goz: it helps to have experience with multiple programming languages (e.g. Perl or Python).

Comment: @Alf: Ill rephrase that final few words then "IMO, it is a bad C++ programming construct".

Comment: @Goz: well, you're stating an opinion on it after stating that *you don't understand it*. Uninformed opinions just mislead others. So, may I suggest reading that blog entry first?

Comment: @Alf: I did read your blog entry and it still left me feelig it was an ugly construct that doesn't make sense.  If you must have an exception whats wrong with using something like apple's XThrowIfError(...) function?  I don't get what your system provides other than for making unreadable code ...

Comment: @Goz: I don't think you're serious.

Comment: @Goz: It lets you deal with the error condition without having to create a local variable to hold the return value of the function that you are checking. That's the only difference I can spot at the moment...there may be others.

Comment: @Sashang: I see that .. but so does XThrowIfError or the SUCCEEDED macro.  Both of those are far more obvious what is going on.

Comment: @Alf:  I AM serious.  I don't get it.

Comment: @Goz: you recognize `SUCCEEDED` because you're used to it. Nothing prevents you from naming your success condition in the same way with the notation above. It (1) addresses the OP's complaint about "endless return codes", doing away with the return code variables and (2) nicely tucking the checking code out to the side of the main code. Plus (3) it centralizes the checking and it (4) centralizes the response. And (5) it provides a visual pattern for easily recognizing (or ignoring) the checking. Might take some time getting familiar with it. When you do it'll be quite clear to you :-)

Comment: @Alf: Succeeded makes sense.  Abusing an operator as you do makes far less sense.  That operator could do anything and that makes it a poor construct, IMO ...

Comment: @Goz: "that operator could do anything" You're saying you'd choose a misleading, uninformative name, and with the ill-chosen name it would not be readable? That's silly. I don't think you're serious.

Comment: @Goz: I haven't said they're unreadable. I've listed the advantages of the notation. You are not serious.

Comment: @Alf: I absoloutely am 100% serious.  All I can say is that I'd slap any of my developers for doing anything like that and I know for a fact that EVERYWHERE I've worked I would have been slapped for doing it as well.

Comment: @Goz: you're telling me of an intense, irrational dislike. sounds religious.

Comment: @Alf:  *Sigh* I'll never convince you, nor am I trying, but abusing operators makes for hard to read and maintain code.  There are plenty of people that agree with me on this as well (Your blog has been passed around to quite a few people so far and not one has had anything but a negative comment on it).  I admit, though, that is not evidence it is anecdote.  In the end, though, do you care what I and others think?

Comment: @Goz: I would be most interested in your *thinking*, yes. And your irrational dislike (no arguments presented so far, just an irrational dislike) is also very interesting. In its own way. :-)

Comment: @Gos: clarifying what I mean by "irrational", e.g. you're saying the notation is abuse, therefore it's bad: it's bad, therefore bad. That's a logical fallacy called *circular logic*. You're citing coworkers feelings; that's both the *authority* fallacy and the fallacy of pure emotion. You imply I've said things I haven't, that's the fallacy of *misrepresentation* plus the fallacy of *straw man* argument. You're suggesting an Apple function for use in Windows programming, that's *complete and utter confusion*. You're calling names and using all uppercase to shout, so on. So, it's irrational.

Comment: @Alf: My argument is that by abusing notation you are creating code where its not instantly obvious what it does.  This lack of obviousness, while not a problem for YOU, presents a serious problem to any 3rd party using your code base (a colleague, for example).  The old argument of "what happens if you get hit by a bus tomorrow?" comes into play.  Code should be easily maintainable by someone OTHER Than yourself and it is this that I am referring to.  I am not suggesting using an apple function in windows programming I am merely suggesting that their solution is instantly more understandable.

Comment: @Guz: you're presenting the *circular logic* fallacy again. calling the notation abusive because you're convinced that that it's non-obvious, inferring from that it must be non-obvious and therefore abusive. it's a long time since last i've seen such a long, continuous stream of fallacies with *no* valid point presented. ;-)

Comment: @Alf:  it IS non obvious.  The >> operator is first and foremost a shift operator.  Secondly it is used for streams.  Using it for something you came up with IS non obvious, by virtue of the fact that YOU came up with it. operators should be used for the purpose they are intended, as this aids the maintainability and understandability of the code base.  I really can't understand how you call this a circular logic fallacy.

Comment: @Goz: after seeing it a few hundred times, do you think you'd be able to recognize it?

Comment: @Alf: Just because you eventually recognise it in YOUR code base does not make it a good construct.  Let me ask you a question, in what way is your construct BETTER than using an if statement?

Comment: @Guz: (1) i have not claimed ownership of the construct, that's the *misrepresentation* fallacy. (2) it's not like it's used only in my code base, not sure of name of that fallacy but it's an *invalid assumption*, similar to *begging the question*. (3) your question implies i haven't listed any advantages, that's again *misprespresentation* fallacy. (4) you're asking for my view on your own undefined notion of "better", which is *meaningless*. (5) it implies I've said "better", that's the fallacy of *misrepresentation*. If you're interested in reasons, check the five advantages listed earlier.

Comment: @Guz: could you also please refrain from shouting.

Comment: @Alf: LOL.  (1) You say in your blog that YOU came up with it.  I have been saying you came up with it.  Where is the misrepresentation? (2) I've never seen it used elsewhere.  Not saying it is but its not exactly STL. (3) None of those are advantages you can perform the same things many different ways. (4) Fair enough, so there are no improvements it brings to the table? (5) Again none of those are advaantages.  They simply state what it does.  Advantage implies it is easier than using a different construct.  Which it doesn't.  Therefore it is not advantageous to use it over other methods.

Comment: @Alf: And don't talk about shouting.  (1) I'm typing. (2) Capitalisation gives emphasis.  It is something I do when typing.  Sorry if you don't like my style, it has "advantages" over using italics :P

Comment: @Goz: re your (1), that's again the fallacy of *misrepresentation*. It's true I came with up with it in the 1990's. It is untrue that I've claimed originality or ownership. After all, Bjarne came up with the idea of using `>>` that way, in the early 1980's. I generally assume that people who read my blog have a modicum of knowledge of the subject area and that they're not antagonistic.

Comment: @Goz: re your (2), you've never recognized something like that elsewhere, well, assuming from that that it isn't used elsewhere is a fallacy of *invalid assumption* or *invalid generalization*. also, assuming from your lack of recognition that you haven't seen it is dubious, to put it mildly.

Comment: @Goz; Re your (3), that you can do things also in other ways does negate the advantages, it is the fallacy of *non sequitur* (a conclusion that does not follow from premises). for example, you can express a `for` loop using `while`, or `goto`. that does not negate the advantages of `for` loops.

Comment: @Goz: re your (4), "so there are no improvements it brings to the table", that's a number of fallacies. it's *misrepresentation*, and it's *non sequitur*, and it's *meaningless*. your production of fallacies is amusing, to put it mildly. :-)

Comment: @Goz: Re your (5), here you claim that none of the advantages are advantages, "therefore it is not advantageous". That's the fallacy of *circular logic* again. Coupled with the fallacy of *baseless claim*. And perhaps some others, i'm sorry, but while amusing this stream of fallacies is getting tedious.

Comment: Are you REALLY saying your idea is not new because Stroustrup used a similar idea for streams?  And you accuse me of fallacy ... Well I give up.  I think the current upvote situation speaks volumes.  I'm gonna leave it at that as you really don't seem to understand.  Thats your choice.

Comment: @Goz: your earlier claims about me claiming ownership or originality, are false. your new claim now about me claiming non-originality, is false. this is again the fallacy of active *misrepresentation*. if you had any valid argument you would have presented it. you have not, instead you have used logical fallacies, name calling, shouting, innuendo, etc. etc.

Comment: That's alotoftext.  Anyway, CComPtr/smart pointers are really the preferred object model for DirectShow.  I wouldn't recommend using anything else.  Also, throwing in DirectShow code can be dangerous, particularly if you're inside a filter.

Comment: @kidjan: thanks for your comments. re first point, actually it's *less* text, because 'if' statements and nesting is avoided, and declarations of result variables are avoided. re second point, yes, that's what I wrote, one should use smart pointers. smart pointers and exceptions go hand in hand. smart pointers support exceptions. they're not mutually exclusive, they're mutually supportive. Cheers,

Comment: I was referring to the flaming above, not your posted answer ;)

w/r/t exceptions, in DShow you really don't want to go there at all.  So to me this is a moot point.