# What DLLs do I #import when using DirectShow or other COM libraries in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, directshow, typelib

I am trying to use [Compiler COM Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h31ekh7e.aspx) when calling DirectShow from C++. From an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4500127/45603) I know that I need to `#import` quartz.dll and qedit.dll. Doing that gives me smart pointer classes like `IGraphBuilderPtr` among others and I can see it supported by IntelliSense. I am now trying to use `ICaptureGraphBuilder2` but it does not show up in the IntelliSense and attempting to `#import` devenum.dll, qcap.dll gives me a `"C1803: Cannot open type library file"`. So, a couple of questions:

1. What DLLs do I need to `#import` when using DirectShow interfaces?
2. In general, given a COM library, how do I know which DLLs I can #import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C++ development you don't need to `#import`. Instead, you

```
#include <dshow.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids.lib")
```

You have smart pointers with ATL, e.g. `CComPtr<IFilterGraph2>` (or `QzCComPtr` which only makes sense if you develop a filter as opposed to high level DirectShow consumer code).

Hence,

> What DLLs do I need to #import when using DirectShow interfaces?

None.

> In general, given a COM library, how do I know which DLLs I can #import?

You need to know the DLL name or rather type library identifier. You get that from documentation or looking using SDK tools like COM/OLE Viewer, or via registry. I would recommend importing using type library identifier.

From C++ code it only makes to import DirectShow DLLs if you need GUIDs, which are deprecated and excluded from SDK.